# Selecting rows with references across tables in SQLite 3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite photo/album database with 3 tables:

**Albums**

```
 id   name           hide
--------------------------
 1    Holiday 2010   1
 2    Day Trip       0
```

**Photos**

```
 id   file
-----------------
 1    photo1.jpg
 2    photo2.jpg
 3    photo3.jpg
 4    photo4.jpg
```

**Relation** (connects photos with albums)

```
 album   photo
-----------------
 1       1
 1       2
 2       3
 2       1
```

A photo can be assigned to zero, one or several albums. Each album has a column 'hide' that indicates, whether the photos of this album should be ignored.

I'm trying to find a SELECT query that returns all photos that are not assigned to an album + all the photos that are in albums which are not hidden (i.e. that have their 'hide' value set to 0).

I came up with a query that selects photos in visible albums, but I don't know how to include the photos that are not assigned to an album:

```
SELECT file 
FROM photos, albums, relation 
WHERE photos.id = relation.photo 
  AND albums.id = relation.album 
  AND albums.hide = 0
```

This query returns:

```
photo1.jpg
photo3.jpg
```

However, the required result would be:

```
photo1.jpg
photo3.jpg
photo4.jpg
```

The problem is photo4.jpg is not assigned to album in the Relation table. Do you know how to solve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of your query retursn photo 1 and 3, so I assume that this is correct.

So you can join and look for null values as this will have no album to join on.

```
SELECT file
FROM photos LEFT OUTER JOIN (relation join albums on relation.album = albums.id)
            ON relation.photo = photos.id
WHERE albums.hide = 0 OR albums.id IS NULL
```